# Angular $resource: Use POST to query array of values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building out search functionality within my Angular app that will allow the user to search by multiple 'tags'. The results of this search will be a list of customers with ANY of the provided tags associated with them.

The problem I'm running into is attempting to pass an array of 'tags' through a `GET` request using `$resource`. In this case is using `POST` and passing this array in the request body the better approach?

Logically this seems like a strict `GET` to me as I'm not altering anything server side, but the array makes it very tricky.

Comment: Why do you consider array of tags tricky? I can imagine a simple yet powerful format for such GET request, i.e. `/api/tags/tag1,tag2,tag3`. Or stick to what simple GET params allow `/api/tags?tag[]=tag1&tag[]=tag2&tag[]=tag3`.

Comment: I don't believe that first approach would work well because I don't know how many tags will be passed. The second approach you mentioned I really like, buy I can't seem to find a way to do it with `$resource`.